# Undefined variable BEFORE SUBMIT is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, post, filter

At first, when I don't use the submit button, there is undefined variable error

> Notice: Undefined variable: results in C:\xampp\htdocs\01test\index.php on line 31
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\01test\index.php on line 31

The code works when submit has been used.

This is my code
`[a link](https://pastebin.com/geBjQDGC/)!`

Everything works fine after the submit button has been used.
But before use it at first, there is two error.

Comment: post code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined variable: results in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\01test\index.php on line 31

According to the above error the statement on line 31 is,

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))`

So according to the error, the problem is in the following statement.

`$results = mysqli_query($dblink, $query) or die (mysqli_error());`

The above statement is inside your `if-else` statement. Since you have declared that variable and assigned inside the `if` statement you will get that error because it can't be accessed from the outside. So I suggest you declare the variable `$results` outside the `if` statement. But hold on you have another error.

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\01test\index.php on line 31

```
$results = mysqli_query($dblink, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
```

From the following statement you are parsing the above variable,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
```

So your `$results` is in the `if-else` statement. But you have called it from outside the `if` statement in `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Your if condition is checking that you submit the post or not. Since you are not submitted and your following code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
```

is outside the if condition `$results` give you `null` value. In brief your code `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))` is calling `$results` if you submitted the post or not. So now you can understand what is the issue.

So finally, your code should be like this,

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "abc";

    $dblink = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($_POST['select']=='all_records') {
            $query = "SELECT Kod_Dorm FROM dorm";
        } elseif($_POST['select']=='A302') {
            $query = "SELECT Kod_Dorm FROM dorm WHERE Kod_Dorm = 'A302'";
        } elseif($_POST['select']=='A303') {
            $query = "SELECT Kod_Dorm FROM dorm WHERE Kod_Dorm = 'A303'";
        }

        $results = mysqli_query($dblink, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

        echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {   //Creates a loop to loop through results
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['Kod_Dorm']."</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
        }

        echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    }
?>
```

By putting the following code inside the if statement will solve your problem because if you only submit the form then it will fetch values. Hope this helps you!

```
echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Kod_Dorm']."</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
```